# Short Circuit Evaluation Order

Tags: javascript, boolean, evaluation, short-circuiting

All this time my thinking of short circuit evaluations seems to be wrong.

In javascript:

```
var a = false, b = true, c=true;
a && b || c; // Evaluates to true
```

Compared to

```
var a = false, b = true, c=true;
a && (b || c); // Evaluates to true
```

Why doesn't the VM stop when it sees that `a` is false?

More explicit example:

```
function a(){
  console.log("I'm A");
  return false;
}
function b(){
  console.log("I'm B");
  return true;
}
function c(){
  console.log("I'm C");
  return true;
}

a() && b() || c();
```

The output is:

```
I'm A
I'm C
true
```

So apparently

```
a && b || c === (a && b) || c
```

So I'm confused, why does it automatically wrap the a && b together? What exactly is the order of operations for these expressions?

Do most languages adhere to this order (PHP seems to be like this)?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: Since elementary school I've always seen `AND` as multiplication and `OR` as addition; given that, it's easier to remember which one has precedence when grouping (in a math expression *multiplication* is calculated before *addition*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These simple rules apply:

- shortcuts in logical expression evaluation does not mean that expressions are evaluated incorrectly, i.e. the result is the same with or witout shortcutting;

- the **AND** boolean operator **(&&)** is of higher precedence than the **OR (||)**. This is why **a && b** are 'wrapped' together;

- it is not safe to rely on precedence order, use parentheses ; this improves readability too;

- most languages do shortcuts when evaluating logical expressions if the result is already defined, incl. PHP; There are exceptions however most notably in reverse polish notation languages like PostScript.