# JS skips latter expressions if the first evaluates to True in an OR operator, does this matter?

Tags: javascript

New to JS. It may be obvious but I am curious if there were edge cases when this behaviour could have unintended effects? (i.e. the latter expressions matter somehow when using OR in an if statement)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short Circuit Evaluation Order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751692/short-circuit-evaluation-order)

Comment: Not really, since there shouldn't be a condition that *needs* to be evaluated. Do you have an example in mind?

Comment: If you don't want it you can use `!!expr1 + !!expr2 + !!expr3` instead of `expr1 || expr2 || expr3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), and it's useful for all sorts of things. It's also not unique to Javascript.

Here is some magical code that relies on short circuit evaluation

```
var person1 = {
   age: 13
};

console.log( "Person 1 age: " + 
    ((typeof person1 !== 'undefined' && person1.age) ? person1.age : "N/A") );
console.log( "Person 2 age: " + 
    ((typeof person2 !== 'undefined' && person2.age) ? person2.age : "N/A") );
```

As you can see, person 2 does not exist, but this code does not throw an error because the short circuit evaluation check never reaches `person2.age`.

The short of it is, for most cases this will not harm you and it will speed up your code. There are ways it can unintentionally break your code if you have a lack of an understanding of it, such as when you assign or add other logical operations inside an if statement.

```
var person1 = {
   age: 13
};

var counter = 0;

console.log( "Person 1 age: " +
    ((typeof person1 !== 'undefined' && person1.age && ++counter) ? person1.age : "N/A") );
console.log( "Person 2 age: " +
    ((typeof person2 !== 'undefined' && person2.age && ++counter) ? person2.age : "N/A") );

console.log(counter);
```

The counter above will be 1. If the `person2` object existed and had an `age` property, the counter would be 2.

This problem can be resolved through restructuring your code.

Comment: Thanks for clarification - I was thinking more about:

        `var myVar;
       
        if (true || myVar = 4) {
            document.write(myVar) // Does not print myVar due to SCE
        }`

But your answer encompasses the point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is in general a bad design if you rely on executing functions within logical expressions.

As other already mentioned most of the programming languages optimize such expressions and don't evaluate it completely if they already know the result (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators, [Short Circuit Evaluation Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751692/short-circuit-evaluation-order))

If you really really want to go this path, you can modify your code and use bitwise operators (`&`, `|`) instead of logical operators (`&&`, `||`), the result should stay the same, but all parts of the expression will be evaluated. But as I mentioned at the beginning this a bad design, and you should rewrite your code.